# How do i Print selected ROWS from web-browser/HTML PAGE table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sendData.JSON.aspx page that sends data to the textfile called Print.txt.
but i want to Print only data that is selected on my web-browser page/HTML PAGE ,NOTE on that web-browser page 
the DATA is selected on a TABLE   . and i have a checkbox column so i want to print all selected ROWS accordingly.
Here is my code to print:

```
    function printSelected() 
    {
        var selecteditems = hesto.ui.getselecteditems('#scannedlabeltable');

        $.each(selecteditems, function (i, item) {

            $.ajax({
            url: SEND_TO_TEXTFILE_PAGE
                    , data: "serial=" + item.id
                        , datatype: 'json'
                        , success: function (status) {
                            if (status.error) {
                                alert(status.error);
                            }
                        }
                        , error: hesto.ajax.errorhandler
            });
        });
```

Comment: How does sending a request to a *text file* works?

Comment: You seem to have some kind of code to extract the selected items (`hesto.ui.getselecteditems('#scannedlabeltable')`). What more precisely is it that you want help with, that is not working?

Comment: @Alex im using a sendData.JSON.aspx page ,but its currenlty it sends everything to Print.text so now i want it to send on selected items

Comment: @Mortb yes this code (hesto.ui.getselecteditems('#scannedlabeltable'))    ,i've added a column for checking ,where you will click a checkbox then it should print only selected items not all

Comment: Not much we can do without seeing the HTML and / or the implementation of the hesto.ui.getselecteditems(...) function